# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '123.0' to data type int

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

This code below reads `xls` file and insert it to my test side. It also checks the database if the values in the `xls` file exist and does comparison with the page title.

The test fails and am giving the following error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '123.0' to data type int.

the forceID in my database is int type and in this code is string but i converted in the following line

```
int q= (int)Double.parseDouble(forceID);
```

PLEASE Help!!! Am using SQL Server 2008 R2, Selenium WebDriver and Java

```
public void loginTest(String forceID,String user,String password)
    throws InterruptedException, IOException, SQLException{
  // test runmode of current dataset
  count++;
  if(!runmodes[count].equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    skip = true;
    throw new SkipException ("Runmode for test set data is set to no"+ count);
  }
  APP_LOGS.debug("Excuting Login Test");
  APP_LOGS.debug(forceID +" -- "+ user +" -- "+ password +" -- ");

  openBrowser();
  driver.get(CONFIG.getProperty("testSiteName"));
  connToDatabase();


  // Check the db
  try{
    pstmt=conn.prepareCall("select * from Login where ForceID=? and Username=? and Password=?");
    pstmt.setString(1,forceID);
    pstmt.setString(2,user);
    pstmt.setString(3,password);
    rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    valueFound =rs.next();
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  //log in to the app
  getObject("forceID").clear();
  int q= (int)Double.parseDouble(forceID);
  getObject("forceID").sendKeys(String.valueOf(q));
  //getObject("forceID").sendKeys(forceID);
  getObject("user").clear();
  getObject("user").sendKeys(user);
  getObject("password").clear();
  getObject("password").sendKeys(password);
  getObject("logOn").click();
  // get the title
  String actual_title=driver.getTitle();
  System.out.println(actual_title);
  System.out.println(valueFound);
  if (valueFound) {
    Assert.assertEquals(actual_title, "Dashboard");
  } else {
    Assert.assertEquals(actual_title, "Logon");
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that you try to insert a String into a field that holds ints? This: `pstmt.setString(1,forceID);` should probably use `setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(ForceID))` or something similar instead.

Comment: Just a clarification where is your exception being thrown? I assumed it was on the rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); line but now I realise you are not specific.

Comment: Thanks jpw and David Waters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a string (the forceId parameter of you java method) to an integer in the database (the ForceID column in your database).

You need to convert forceID from a string to an integer in your java code and pass it to your prepared statment as an integer.

```
pstmt.setInt(1, (int)Double.parseDouble(fourceID));
```